# Use folder of multiple files from s3 in AWS Sagemaker Notebook

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I want to read multiple files from a folder that is in S3 bucket. I want to get access of complete files of that folder and use them using AWS Sagemaker Notebook. How can I done this??

Comment: S3 Web console make prefixes look like "folders", but remember they are actually just object name prefixes.  You can list objects by prefix with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to download all files from an S3 path. For reading you can just replace the download_file with get_object call.

```
def download_data(cls,s3_path:str,local_path:str):
        
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
        bucket,key_prefix = cls._parse_s3_path(s3_path)
        
        # Initialize the variables used to loop through the contents of the S3 bucket.
        keys = []
        next_token = ""
        base_parameters = {"Bucket": bucket, "Prefix": key_prefix}
    
        # Loop through the contents of the bucket, 1,000 objects at a time. Gathering all keys into
        # a "keys" list.
        while next_token is not None:
            request_parameters = base_parameters.copy()
            if next_token != "":
                request_parameters.update({"ContinuationToken": next_token})
            response = s3.list_objects_v2(**request_parameters)
            contents = response.get("Contents")
            # For each object, save its key or directory.
            for s3_object in contents:
                key = s3_object.get("Key")
                keys.append(key)
            next_token = response.get("NextContinuationToken")
    
        # For each object key, create the directory on the local machine if needed, and then
        # download the file.
        for key in keys:
            if key.endswith("/"):
                continue
            tail_s3_uri_path = os.path.basename(key)
            if not os.path.splitext(key_prefix)[1]:
                tail_s3_uri_path = os.path.relpath(key, key_prefix)
            destination_path = os.path.join(local_path, tail_s3_uri_path)
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(destination_path)):
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination_path))
            s3.download_file(
                Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Filename=destination_path
            )
```